# POST Request not successfully sending mail over SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, post, smtp

I am trying to send a mail over SMPT using my webhost as a mail client.
This my my code for the controller:

```
try
            {
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("info@lovbjerg-rema1000-sommerhus.dk.dk");
                mailMessage.To.Add("my@email.dk");

                mailMessage.Subject = "Kontakt mail";
                mailMessage.Body = "Navn: " + model.Navn + "\nAddresse: " + model.Addresse + ", " +
                    model.PostNrBy + "\nTelefon: " + model.Telefon + "\n" + model.Message;

                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.curanet.dk", 25)
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    EnableSsl = true
                };

                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

My mail settings in my web.config:

```
<mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="info@lovbjerg-rema1000-sommerhus.dk">
        <network host="smtp.curanet.dk" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

A POST request is made to the page, but I never receive the mail (replace my@email.dk with my own mail). The web host does not require a username and password to use their SMTP client, so I set the default credentials to true.

I can't see any error in my code, and I tried using several SMTPClient datatypes which all gave the same result. Are my settings for the SMTPClient wrong? Am I missing some property?

Comment: Try a different SMTP service so that you may determine if the error is with the SMTP service or your application.

Comment: consider verifying clutter's (spam) settings/folder

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint to make sure your sending code is ever reached?

Comment: Should `lovbjerg-rema1000-sommerhus.dk.dk` be `lovbjerg-rema1000-sommerhus.dk`?